# Knative On-Premise setup without external IP

Tags: networking, kubernetes, internal-dns

I am trying to setup Knative on On-Premise Kubernetes Cluster (without having an external ip).

```
Kubernetes: v1.28
Knative: v1.13
1 master node and 2 workers
```

https://knative.dev/docs/install/yaml-install/serving/install-serving-with-yaml/

In Configure DNS section, I have chosen no DNS, as Magic DNS requires external ip. Now after registering a function I am not able to call it via HTTP request.

```
$ kubectl get kservice fibonacci-single -n knative-serverless
NAME               URL                                                            LATESTCREATED            LATESTREADY              READY   REASON
fibonacci-single   http://fibonacci-single.knative-serverless.svc.cluster.local   fibonacci-single-00001   fibonacci-single-00001   True
```

I have also tried creating a private cluster-local service.
https://knative.dev/docs/serving/services/private-services/

```
curl http://fibonacci-single.knative-serverless.svc.cluster.local
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: fibonacci-single.knative-serverless.svc.cluster.local
```

I cannot use external IP. How can I access my function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried setting up network using Magic DNS explained [here](https://opensource.com/article/20/11/knative). I believe this is not provided in the official installation guide.

```
# Install Magic DNS
kubectl apply -f https://github.com/knative/serving/releases/download/knative-v1.13.1/serving-default-domain.yaml
# Get ClusterIP:
kubectl --namespace kourier-system get service kourier
# Use ClusterIP to patch config-domain
# ClusterIP.nip.io
kubectl patch configmap -n knative-serving config-domain -p "{\"data\": {\"10.96.30.55.nip.io\": \"\"}}"
```

Now this works without Domain name and External IP:

`curl http://fibonacci-single.knative-serverless.10.96.30.55.nip.io?x=1000`

Answer (score 0):

Implement IPv6, and your own domain name with "real DNS", to use Knative's phrase.

Kubernetes supports IPv6, and those Knative docs provide a reference for several Kubernetes ingress options. Surely there exists a way for the service address to use modern IP.

The default-domain, "magic DNS" thing via sslip.io, is a demonstration thing unnecessary for production use cases. Apparently it uses an IP address embedded name service?  I assume this is going through hoops to not do certificates with IP address subjects.  And no IPv6 does you no good if you don't have an "external" IP.

Use your domain name and a wildcard, resolving to the ingress. .local is reserved for mDNS, do not use it here.

Naturally, if the services aren't intended to be available to the internet, don't make the names resolvable or the IPs routable. However, you still can do a proper named service. Making up values, maybe  `*.knative.example.net` in your private DNS resolves to the ingress at `2001:db8:115:5995::285`. And this v6 network is filtered at the firewall per your desired security policy.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I couldn't get Domain name or External IP on my network. I found a way using Magic DNS.